# Loop through folder of .TXT files and copy their contents

Tags: excel, vba, loops, text

I'm trying to automate the following:

1. Open .TXT file
2. Select All
3. Copy
4. Paste onto Excel Sheet
5. Repeat

I have 150 text files in a directory, which I would like to open, copy all contents and paste onto an excel sheet, with an offset of 'c'

Each file has exactly 95 rows, so after pasting `C:\myDir\MyFile1` in A1, for example. I'd like to paste the contents of the next .txt file in A101.

So far I have cobbled together some bits of code:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim C as integer
    StrFile = Dir("E:\my path")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Workbooks.Open(StrFile)
        Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy ws.range("A"& c)
        Workbook.Close
        C = C + 100     'Each txt file = 95 rows
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Though this isn't iterating through the list.

Comment: You `Dim wb As Workbook` but the variable is never set. So something like `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(StrFile)` so you can use it later like `wb.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy …` etc. Also `ws` is never set to any worksheet. • Fix that first, then update your code in the question and always tell which errors you get in which line.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the "Power Query" Add-in of Excel (in Excel 2016 this is in the product by default).
With Power Query, you will be able to simply select the folder where your files are located and append all the data very easily without any need for coding. You can also modify the data as needed once in the Power Query editor.

[Power Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uAcz.png)

[example combining 2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s0QE.png)

[Power Query UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8lxb.png)

Comment: Recommendation of software is off-topic on StackOverflow which can also appear as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Just added a var for the workbook which contains the workbook `csvWb` and concatenating the `folder` (in case the excel file is not in the folder). Furthermore Excel does not like copying multiple entire sheets which are overlapping in the target, so lets restrict ourselves to `Rows("1:95")` (which saves memory and time). Intentionally omitted any error handling (files might be locked) to keep the example short.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim C As Integer
    Dim csvWb As Workbook
    Dim folder As String
    folder = "E:\my path\"
    StrFile = Dir(folder)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    C = 1
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set csvWb = Workbooks.Open(folder & StrFile)
        csvWb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:95").Copy ws.Range("A" & C) 'Each txt file = 95 rows
        csvWb.Close
        C = C + 100     'Each txt file = 95 rows
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```